# Salesforce CLI deploy files with spaces failing

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx-cli, ci, cli

I am trying to deploy files to a non-source tracked org with the cli `deploy` command as follows:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -u [ORG] -p "force-app/main/default/layouts/Snapshot__mdt-Snapshot Layout.layout-meta.xml"
```

but am getting this error:

```
ERROR running force:source:deploy:  The Layout named Snapshot__mdt-Snapshot Layout was not found in the workspace.
```

I've tried `-p ''"[path/to/file]"''` and `-p "\"[path/to/file]\""` and neither worked.

The file definitely exists and I am able to use the beta `diff` command from VSCode on this file.

So how do we include files with spaces in the name in our `-p` arg?

Comment: You need to use the `"` double quotes to be able to include space. Try prefixing `./` to the path like `"./force-app/main/default/..."`.

Comment: No luck.  Also any other file which doesn't contain spaces deploys fine with our without `./`

Comment: The command that you have added is working for me(first one). Just that my deployment is failed because of an empty file and dependencies.

Comment: This is happening from friday with me, all other deployments are failing on push command. For layouts only.

Comment: Worked fine for me to deploy on a Windows 10 PC with CLI version 7.65.2 with double quotes and then again when I updated the CLI to 7.69.0. It might be relevant to look at your version.

Comment: Key here is which OSX are you all on! Can we get OS information and versions ?

Comment: Catalina 10.15.3, thanks Mohith

Comment: It's running on docker with linux, on windows working fine. It's downloading the sfdx at the runtime and pushing the force-app with sfdx cli commands and then it starts failing.my command is simple in pipeline(similar to this)  `sfdx force: source:push --targetusername newscratchorgalias || sfdx force:org: delete --targetusername newscratchorgalias`

Comment: I am talking about the `deploy` command specifically, along with the -p argument and including files with spaces in the name as part of that argument.  I have no problem with any other command nor deploy for files without spaces.

Comment: yes Shane, I just added comment because it's throwing error for layouts only.

Answer (score 3):

OK I figured it out on Mac OSX.  For a single file `-p` works as follows:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p "force-app/main/default/layouts/Snapshot__mdt-Snapshot Layout.layout-meta.xml"
```

However, for multiple files with your `-p` argument, you need to surround each filename with escaped double quotes as follows:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p """force-app/main/default/layouts/SnapshotDetail__mdt-SnapshotDetail Layout.layout-meta.xml"",""force-app/main/default/layouts/Snapshot__mdt-Snapshot Layout.layout-meta.xml"""
```

And finally, another problem I had, make sure none of the files are in your `.forceignore` or you will get the `Not Found In Workspace` error.